# Where to enter commands to compile and run C program that resides in gedit?

Tags: compiling, gedit

I am running Ubuntu. Please advise where I should enter the command to compile the C++ program that I have entered in gedit. 
Please also advise if I need to relocate the C program before trying to compile and run it, and where I should relocate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file somewhere as `program.cpp` then open a terminal and cd to the directory you saved the file.

To compile the program with gcc run `gcc -o program program.cpp`. If there are no errors in the program this will output a binary with your compiled program called `program` which you can run with `./program` in the terminal.